# corr.mtest function changes correlation coefficients?

Tags: r, correlation

I needed to calculate correlations in a dataframe and to highlight only the significant ones. I found this function here on stackoverflow.

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):n){
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level)
      p.mat[i,j] <- p.mat[j,i] <- tmp$p.value
      lowCI.mat[i,j] <- lowCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
      uppCI.mat[i,j] <- uppCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
    }
  }
  return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}
```

I operate on my database and I calculate the correlations

```
my_df <- cor(my_df)
head(mydf)

> head(my_df)


##             V1          V2          V3         V4         V5         V6         V7         V8
## V1  1.00000000 -0.09483036  0.08496371  0.3022391  0.5626154 -0.2483336  0.1096767  0.2441640
## V2 -0.09483036  1.00000000  0.45397343  0.8459913 -0.5454400  0.3609005 -0.2278882 -0.3699623
## V3  0.08496371  0.45397343  1.00000000  0.7579513 -0.1285077 -0.1381399 -0.5044181 -0.2756256
## V4  0.30223914  0.84599133  0.75795133  1.0000000 -0.2444336  0.1124788 -0.3283376 -0.2769132
## V5  0.56261538 -0.54543998 -0.12850765 -0.2444336  1.0000000 -0.4929598  0.1378570  0.2633717
## V6 -0.24833365  0.36090049 -0.13813990  0.1124788 -0.4929598  1.0000000 -0.2517067  0.3912901
```

I apply the function to obtain significances and then I create a corrplot

```
cor1 <- cor.mtest(my_df, 0.95)

plotted_corrmat <-corrplot(cor(my_df), p.mat = cor1[[1]] , insig = "blank", method = "color", 
             addCoef.col="black" ,
             order = "original", tl.cex = 1/par("cex"), 
             cl.cex = 1/par("cex"), addCoefasPercent = TRUE)
```

but the coefficients change (and also the significances change if I add another variable -coloumn - in the original dataframe, or if I consider the correlation between two old variables in a dataframe with new variables)

```
head(plotted_corrmat)


##             V1         V2          V3         V4         V5         V6         V7         V8
## V1  1.00000000 -0.4808666 -0.07645303 -0.1426384  0.7927122 -0.6805792  0.1983160  0.1665963
## V2 -0.48086660  1.0000000  0.73402255  0.9096073 -0.8505173  0.4304575 -0.6465926 -0.7499984
## V3 -0.07645303  0.7340225  1.00000000  0.9204683 -0.4071524 -0.0452260 -0.8033922 -0.7459460
## V4 -0.14263840  0.9096073  0.92046835  1.0000000 -0.5955864  0.1353852 -0.7492527 -0.8040587
## V5  0.79271216 -0.8505173 -0.40715236 -0.5955864  1.0000000 -0.7342590  0.4391327  0.4262626
## V6 -0.68057919  0.4304575 -0.04522600  0.1353852 -0.7342590  1.0000000 -0.3788302  0.2120725
```

Comment: Please take the time to review your question's format.

Comment: A more specific suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks